# Proxy server that can optionally load cached URLs in Python's Twisted

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I have built a very simple proxy server using Twisted that returns web pages from the internet.

What I want is for the server to have two states:

1. Any URL is requested from the internet and returned (as in a normal proxy server).
2. For any URL we first search to see if we have a copy stored locally (and if so return it). Otherwise we request the URL from the internet, save the result and then return the result.

I have currently just implemented (1) using one of the basic examples in Twisted.

```
# proxy.py

from twisted.web import proxy, http
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.python import log
import sys


log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
    protocol = proxy.Proxy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, ProxyFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

This can be tested by running for example

```
python proxy.py
```

and in another terminal

```
curl -x localhost:8080 http://example.com
```

How would I modify this code so that it includes the functionality for (2)?

Comment: You should try something and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Can you advise on what you did not find specific enough? I want to implement point (2) which seems like it should only be 5-10 lines of code max. Essentially I don't know how to perform the logic for getting the proxy to first check the URL against a list of currently cached URLs and then modifying the response as a result of this.

Comment: The question reads as "Implement a caching HTTP server for me".  Instead, try to implement a caching HTTP server and when you run into trouble, ask about that trouble.  Or, if you can't even figure out how to start, try to articulate that difficulty better.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a think and try to modify.